# Como Solucionar Definitivamente el Error/Advertencia de ADB.exe es Obsoleto y la GPU Make:8086?

Tags: android-studio, adb, gpu

Compañeros

La Siguiente Imagen Se muestra luego de haber arrancado el Emulador de Android Studio. He intentado dejar en una sola actualización del SDK Tools, la opcion de "Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc1. La cual funciona momentáneamente eliminando las versiones anteriores, sin embargo al reiniciar se encuentra nuevamente palomeada una opción de versión Inferior a la 30.0.0-rc1, la cual es la 28.0.3.

Adicional mente aparece un Cuadro de Dialogo que se presenta con carácter de que un Error se a Producido o esta inmersa alguna configuración pendiente por realizarse de la GPU-Make 8086.

================================================================================================

## Aparision del Error/Advertencia   ==> adb.exe es obsoleto <==

[image: Error de adb.exe es obsoleto al momento del arranque del emulador]

---

### Intento de solución(momentánea) para el Error del ===> adb.exe es obsoleto <===

[image: Eliminación de la Actualización Anterior para la soluciona del "adb.exe es obsoleto"]

==============================================================================================

## Cuadro de Información de la GPU, presunto Error o Configuración pendiente de solucionar.

[image: Cuadro Informativo de la GPU-Make 8086]

## **Agradezco su Ayuda. Que se debería realizar para solucionar esos problemas y sobretodo cual es el motivo que los genera.**

Answer (score 0):

1.- Doble Shift para abrir el cuadro de búsqueda.

2.- Tipo SDK Manager

3.- En los resultados mostrados, haga clic en "SDK Manager".

4.- En la ventana que se abre, haga clic en la segunda pestaña "Herramientas de SDK".
5.- Debería ver que hay una actualización disponible para SDK Build-Tools en la primera línea

6.- Marque "Mostrar detalles del paquete" en la esquina inferior derecha

7.- Desplácese hasta el último elemento en "SDK Build-Tools" y marque la casilla. (La mía era 30.0.0)

8.- Haga clic en "Aplicar"

9.- En el cuadro de diálogo que aparece, haga clic en "Aceptar"

10.- Cuando el instalador termine, haga clic en "Finalizar"

11.- Desmarque "Mostrar detalles del paquete" y vea "Herramientas de desarrollo del SDK de Android" (primera línea). No debería haber ninguna actualización disponible y debería decir "Instalado"

12.- Haga clic en "Aceptar" para cerrar el Administrador de SDK

Eso es todo al respecto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Cristina por tu ayuda con el inconveniente suscitado, es decir, que este problema se genera por las actualizaciones que no se ejecutan periódicamente o por la alguna instalación que luego de ser finalizada no se realiza ninguna configuración en AStudio?. Gracias de Antemano